# CakePHP ignores condition

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have the following problem with CakePHP:

Two tables are joined (filters and accounts). Then I am building conditions and only the second condition `Account.active =>1` gets executed. If I print the result, there are still showing filters that are having another `mode_id` than 3.

```
$joins= array( 
    array('table' => 'filters',
          'alias' => 'Filter',
          'type' => 'right',
          'conditions' => array(
          'Filter.account_id = Account.id',
                )
            ),
        );
```

Then I execute the request including joins and conditions

```
$activeAccounts = $this->Account->find('all',array(
 'conditions'=>array('AND'=>array('Filter.mode_id'=>3,'Account.active'=>1)),
 'joins'=>$joins));
```

The models were checked and no problems identified. Filter belongs to Account. Account has many Filter.

Below the query that is generated. The results are still showing filters with Filter.mode_id other than 3

Here is the query that is generated. The results are still containing rows with Filter.mode_id other than 3 despite the fact that one condition is 'Filter.mode_id'=>3

```
SELECT `Account`.`id`, `Account`.`user_id`, `Account`.`name`, 
`Account`.`api_key`, `Account`.`account_number`, `Account`.`remaining_balance`, 
`Account`.`investment_size`, `Account`.`active` 
FROM `baseline_db`.`accounts` AS `Account` 
right JOIN `baseline_db`.`filters` AS `Filter` 
  ON (`Filter`.`account_id` = `Account`.`id`) 
WHERE ((`Filter`.`mode_id` = 3) AND 
(`Account`.`active` = '1'))
```

Comment: Associations would have no bearing if you're doing a manual join.  Please provide the query it's generating.

Comment: Any reason why you're not using [Model associations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html)? This will make your life much easier.

Comment: It won't solve your problem, but you should not be using a **right** join. An **inner** join should be used. Try setting your recursive flag to -1 for this find. _(Notice that the generated query does not return any filters table's columns. You really should be using the [containable behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html))_.

Comment: Thanks. With inner join and containable     'contain'=>array('Filter') still no luck. It's still ignoring the condition 'Filter.mode_id' => 3

Answer (score 0):

Like say Oldskool, use the Model associations 
and for your condition, The "AND" is not necessary,
you cant put :

```
$activeAccounts = $this->Account->find('all',array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Filter.mode_id'=>3,
        'Account.active'=>1
    )
));
```

Comment: I tried but I am getting "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Filter.mode_id' in 'where clause". I wonder if I made a mistake in the model association.

Comment: Your condition's filter cannot have fields from a model that is related via hasMany.

Answer (score 0):

the request you want to make with the type of relation you have,  seem to me weird.
If i understand, perhaps with something like that :

```
$this->loadModel('Filter');
$filters =$this->Filter->find("list", array(
    'conditions' => array('Filter.mode_id' => 3),
    'fields' => array('Filter.account_id')
));
$activeAccounts = $this->Account->find('all',array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Account.account_id'=>$filters,
        'Account.active'=>1
    )
));
```

Comment: Thanks, Mato. Problem is, then I have two different requests. I want to have one result and eliminate all accounts that are not active and all filters that are not in mode 3. Mode 3 means that the filter is active. Bottom line: One request with all accounts containing active filters that are associated to them.